# Power BI - Automating data exports

Tags: powerbi, power-automate

I'm looking for a way to automatically export data from Power BI visualizations to CSV or excel. If you click on the more options on each visualization, it gives you the option to export the underlying data used to create each visual
[image: As shown here]

Is there a way to make Power Bi export the data every time the dashboard is refreshed? I tried using power automate within Power Bi to export the data and it works but it seems there isn't a way to schedule the button to run every time the data is refreshed.

Comment: You need to try with Power Automate.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using [Analyze in Excel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-analyze-in-excel) instead of exporting from the visual, since it estabishes a live OLAP connection directly to the Power BI dataset which is always up-to-date. And in contrast to exports from visuals it gives you access to the whole data model and doesn't come with a row limit.